# WKWebKit errore - Connection interrupted [XPC] Handle connection with error: Connection interrupted

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am facing one issue with WKWekView in iOS. I have an app running in WKWebView and opening native UI on click of button.

When i open the native UI i cancel the request to load in WkWebView like below -

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

        if let url = navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString {
        if URLString.contains("mobile://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")  {           
            self.loadNativeUI()
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            return
        }
}
```

If i open native ui i am getting the logs in WKWebView -

```
[Database] Encountered xpc error for ClientInUse response with error: Connection interrupted
[XPC] Handle connection with error: Connection interrupted
[shim] BKSProcessAssertion "ConnectionTerminationWatchdog" initialized with invalid pid
[shim] BKSProcessAssertion "ConnectionTerminationWatchdog" initialized with invalid pid
[ProcessSuspension] 0x10bac4d80 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
[ProcessSuspension] 0x10bac6a30 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
[ProcessSuspension] 0x10bac6a90 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
```

What is the meaning of these errors? Why WKWebView reloads at this point? 
Appreciate for any help!!

Comment: have you found an answer?